# how to read data from text file and pass them to junit test as parameterized test in java?

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

So Im doing JUnit Tests. While Im getting the parameters for my test method in a text document I counter an issue that is after the parameter object is not working well. All my parameter pass to the test method at once but I want them to pass separately.

Image below is what I want(Red line means the second set of parameters). The image is a sample run of my test method.

https://ibb.co/nFLhOc

This is my code:

```
    String fileName = "ChargeData.txt";

    try 
    {
        scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<Object[]> Params = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    List listOfLists = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList <Integer> quantityList;
    ArrayList <Boolean> highQualityList;
    ArrayList <Boolean> designEffectList;
    ArrayList <Double> expectedResultList;

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        quantityList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        highQualityList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        designEffectList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        expectedResultList = new ArrayList<Double>();

        while(scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            quantityList.add(new Integer(scan.next()));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<quantityList.size();i++)
        {
            highQualityList.add(new Boolean(scan.next()));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<quantityList.size();i++)
        {
            designEffectList.add(new Boolean(scan.next()));
        }
        expectedResultList.add(new Double(scan.next()));

        int[] quantity = new int[quantityList.size()];
        boolean[] highQuality = new boolean[quantityList.size()];
        boolean[] designEffect = new boolean[quantityList.size()];
        double[] expectedResult = new double[1];
        for (int i=0; i < quantity.length; i++)
        {
            quantity[i] = quantityList.get(i).intValue();
            highQuality[i] = highQualityList.get(i).booleanValue();
            designEffect[i] = designEffectList.get(i).booleanValue();
        }
        expectedResult[0] = expectedResultList.get(0).doubleValue();

        listOfLists.add(quantity);
        listOfLists.add(highQuality);
        listOfLists.add(designEffect);
        listOfLists.add(expectedResult);
    }
    Params.add(listOfLists.toArray());

    scan.close();

    return Params.toArray();
}
```

Comment: You can use parameterized tests : https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Comment: Hmm i just figured it out, my Params.add() should be inside the loop. Anyways thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Logic problem, just move the `Params.add(listOfLists.toArray());` inside while loop fixed it.

```
while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        quantityList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        highQualityList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        designEffectList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        expectedResultList = new ArrayList<Double>();

        while(scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            quantityList.add(new Integer(scan.next()));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<quantityList.size();i++)
        {
            highQualityList.add(new Boolean(scan.next()));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<quantityList.size();i++)
        {
            designEffectList.add(new Boolean(scan.next()));
        }
        expectedResultList.add(new Double(scan.next()));

        int[] quantity = new int[quantityList.size()];
        boolean[] highQuality = new boolean[quantityList.size()];
        boolean[] designEffect = new boolean[quantityList.size()];
        double[] expectedResult = new double[1];
        for (int i=0; i < quantity.length; i++)
        {
            quantity[i] = quantityList.get(i).intValue();
            highQuality[i] = highQualityList.get(i).booleanValue();
            designEffect[i] = designEffectList.get(i).booleanValue();
        }
        expectedResult[0] = expectedResultList.get(0).doubleValue();

        listOfLists.add(quantity);
        listOfLists.add(highQuality);
        listOfLists.add(designEffect);
        listOfLists.add(expectedResult);
        Params.add(listOfLists.toArray());
    }
```